# Can an apt proxy affect the use of dpkg?

Tags: dpkg, proxy, preseed

I have been doing Ubuntu deployment using a preseed.cfg.  After becoming comfortable with the packages being installed it was time to reduce download time and internet traffic by creating a mirror.  I ended up doing a "partial mirror" using [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) and preseeding it by adding

```
d-i mirror/http/proxy string http://mymirror
```

to the preseed.cfg.  This is where things got strange.  I have a few .debs that I run as part of preseed/late_command by wgetting them and installing them with dpkg -i.  The packages were installing without issue until added the proxy.  With the proxy they fail to install.  So does the proxy affect installing .debs during preseeded installation?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this was an issue with some of additional files being downloaded using ASCII as opposed to binary and becoming corrupted.